# Create method not working because id keeps returning zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1, and I'm trying to create a user. But when I run the web application and try to create a user, the Id returns 0. I've tried using a hidden field in my razor view but the ID still returns zero and the user is not added.

Here's my user class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int FacultyID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string LGA { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the create method in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    var fac = await _faculty.GetAll();
    var dept = await _department.GetAll();
    var facList = fac.Select(f => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = f.facultyName.ToString(),
        Text = f.facultyName
    });
    var deptList = dept.Select(d => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = d.deptName.ToString(),
        Text = d.deptName
    });
    ViewBag.fac = facList;
    ViewBag.dept = deptList;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(User user)
{
    var createUser = await _userService.AddAsync(user);

    if (createUser)
    {
        Alert("User created successfully.", NotificationType.success);
        return RedirectToAction("ListUsers", "User");
    }
    else
    {
        Alert("User not created!", NotificationType.error);
    }

    return View();
}
```

And here's the razor view for adding the user:

```
<form asp-controller="User" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" />
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input asp-for="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input asp-for="LastName" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="Username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input asp-for="Username" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Username"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="Country" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input asp-for="Country" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Country"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="State" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">State</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select asp-for="State" class="mb-2 form-control" onchange="toggleLGA(this);" name="state" id="state">
                <option value="" selected="selected">- State -</option>
                <option value="Abia">Abia</option>
                <option value="Adamawa">Adamawa</option>
                <option value="AkwaIbom">AkwaIbom</option>
                <option value="Anambra">Anambra</option>
                <option value="Bauchi">Bauchi</option>
                <option value="Bayelsa">Bayelsa</option>
                <option value="Benue">Benue</option>
                <option value="Borno">Borno</option>
                <option value="Cross River">Cross River</option>
                <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
                <option value="Ebonyi">Ebonyi</option>
                <option value="Edo">Edo</option>
                <option value="Ekiti">Ekiti</option>
                <option value="Enugu">Enugu</option>
                <option value="FCT">FCT</option>
                <option value="Gombe">Gombe</option>
                <option value="Imo">Imo</option>
                <option value="Jigawa">Jigawa</option>
                <option value="Kaduna">Kaduna</option>
                <option value="Kano">Kano</option>
                <option value="Katsina">Katsina</option>
                <option value="Kebbi">Kebbi</option>
                <option value="Kogi">Kogi</option>
                <option value="Kwara">Kwara</option>
                <option value="Lagos">Lagos</option>
                <option value="Nasarawa">Nasarawa</option>
                <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                <option value="Ogun">Ogun</option>
                <option value="Ondo">Ondo</option>
                <option value="Osun">Osun</option>
                <option value="Oyo">Oyo</option>
                <option value="Plateau">Plateau</option>
                <option value="Rivers">Rivers</option>
                <option value="Sokoto">Sokoto</option>
                <option value="Taraba">Taraba</option>
                <option value="Yobe">Yobe</option>
                <option value="Zamfara">Zamafara</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="LGA" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">LGA</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select asp-for="LGA" name="lga" id="lga" class="mb-2 form-control select-lga" required>
                <option value="" selected="selected">- Local Government -</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="Faculty" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Faculty</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="mb-2 form-control" asp-for="Faculty" asp-items="@ViewBag.fac">
                <option>Faculty</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Faculty"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="Department" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="mb-2 form-control" asp-for="Department" asp-items="@ViewBag.dept">
                <option>Department</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Department"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input asp-for="Email" type="email" class="form-control"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="PhoneNo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input asp-for="PhoneNo" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNo"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative row form-group">
        <label asp-for="Grade" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Grade</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input asp-for="Grade" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Grade"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="position-relative row form-check">
            <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
                <button asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: You are trying to create a new User, so it is not expected to has an Id yet, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But the create method isn't working, so I figured that was the problem.

Comment: You can try and debug `Create(User user)` and `_userService.AddAsync(user)` methods.

Comment: I did, and it just shows that everything is good except the integer properties (Id, DepartmentID, and FacultyID)

Comment: Is _userService a DbContext? If so, you need to call _userService.SaveChangesAsync(). The data is not persisted to the database until this is called.

Comment: _userService is a DbContext, and I did call the SaveChangesAsync() method in a separate file.

Comment: How are you instantiating _userService?  You need to call SaveChangesAsync on the same instance that you add your user to in your controller, or there will be no changes to save.  If you are not using dependency injection or passing the same instance to the "other file," your new user may not exist in the context that is saving.

Comment: @ShawnPaige yes I did use a dependency injection and I did pass the same instance to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove     `<input asp-for="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" />`

---

`Id` will automatically add after `SaveChangesAsync()`.

If you set a `<input>` element of `Id` in `Create` view, it will only read value from `<input>`.

> Test

Before `SaveChangesAsync`

[image]

After `SaveChangesAsync`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It was very helpful in solving my problem.